# User permissions to custom user model in Django

Tags: python, django

I have custom user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Our own User model. Made by overriding Django's own AbstractUser model.
    We need to define this as the main user model in settings.py with 
    variable AUTH_USER_MODEL *IMPORTANT* 
    """
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name="email address"
    )
    institute = models.ForeignKey(
        Institute, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I have two users in my projects. One is the super admin and the other is the admin. I've specified the model for admin as such:

```
class AdminUser(User):
    is_admin = False
    is_staff = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name+" "+self.last_name

    # Control model features
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Admin User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Admin Users'
```

Now I want to revoke access of the entire user model from this Admin User. How could this be achieved? We are going to have many more user types in future. They will be specified through models.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by just using groups in Django.

Your superuser will be you, that will have all permissions for default using the field `is_admin=True`. The second user can be a simple Staff user that is member of the group "Admins", just create the group and assign all the permissions to that group except the permissions to Add, Change and Delete users.

That will do the trick.

**Update**: If you need more complex cases, you can use the app `django-groups-manager` or `django-guardian` So you can create groups in trees, there you can use more domain driven permission rules.**

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this without groups? We are building a heirarchy. There's also going to be a Director and a domain principal. So the Director can create users in Domain Principals and both of them can create users in AdminUser. Then of course the users at the end of the heirarchy shouldn't be able to change users above them.

Comment: You can use `django-groups-manager` or `django-guardian` You can not simple solve this, either use a third party app or create your own Group/Domain model where you start adding all your logic and extend the User to check for permissions in a Custom model from your own.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try this.